# Attunity SSIS not available in SSIS Data Flow Tasks

Tags: oracle, ssis, connector

I installed the Attunity SSIS connector from the below link into my machine. My machine is a Windows 7 Laptop, and I am using Visual Studio 2008 as my IDE to create my integration service project. Now according to the help provided with Attunity, I should be able to choose the oracle connectors from the "Choose toolbox items -> SSIS Data flow tasks", however the connectors are just not available in the list. I verified the program files folder and I can see the Attunity folder along with the language folders. I already restarted my machine as well. Is there anything I am missing to use these connectors?

Download: 
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=29283

Comment: Do you need to add a DSN using this connector? Not sure if that rule applies to attunity, but just saying.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have installed the wrong version of the Attunity SSIS connector. The link that you had provided contains the connector for `SSIS 2012` and *not* for SSIS 2008.

Here is the link to the correct Attunity connector for `SSIS 2008`

[**Microsoft® Connectors v1.2 for Oracle and Teradata**](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=29284)

I installed the above version and I can see the connectors displayed on *SSIS Data Flow Items* in `Choose toolbox items` dialog.

[image: Attunity connector]