# Attunity connectors are not showing in SSIS for VS 2017, SQL Server 2017

Tags: ssis, attunity

I have seen this post for VS 2015 but not VS 2017.

I have tested Visual Studio 2017 SSDT - both Enterprise and Professional, and SQL Server 2017. I followed the post [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssis/2017/05/22/if-you-face-an-issue-when-the-attunity-connectors-arent-visible-in-the-ssis-toolbox/) and tried installing the Attunity Connectors for Oracle both V5 (found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55179)) like they recommended (didn't work) and V4 ([here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52950)) as was recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43884703/ssis-microsoft-connector-for-oracle-by-attunity-for-vs2015-not-showing) (still didn't work). I am still not seeing it in SSIS. Is there yet another recommended way to get the connector to show up in SSIS or is there a process to add them manually to VS 2017? TIA

Note as a further edit, tried this on Windows 2016 server, Windows 10, SQL Server Enterprise and Developer Editions.

Comment: What kind of license do you have for SQL 2017? The connectors will only work if you have Enterprise or Developer.

Comment: Installed architecture x64 or x86 or Both??

Comment: I tried both Developer and Enterprise editions, also tried x64 only and both installs. Of the 8 possible combinations of Win10/Win2016, SQL Ent/Dev and x64/Both I have tried 7 of them with exactly the same result. I have also uninstalled/reinstalled VS 2017/Attunity to see if the order of install might have something to do with it, but no luck. Altogether I have probably tried 10-12 different combinations with the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't mention the version of SSDT you have installed, but you are likely running into a known issue with the most recent versions, specifically 15.8.1 and higher do not appear to support the Attunity drivers.

Ref: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0d45473-eea6-4d19-a708-25ceb79bf920/ssdt-for-visual-studio-2017-1590-and-oracle-connector-requirements?forum=ssdt

The short answer appears to be that you will need to install 15.8.0 or prior SSDT versions in order to take advantage of the Attunity connectors.