# Install Oracle Attunity Drivers in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, oracle, visual-studio, ssis, attunity

I am trying to make a demo install for the future environment of your SSIS (Extraction / Transformation) layer. For this to be successful I need the Oracle Attunity Drivers.

I have installed:

1. Visual Studio 15.9.7
2. SQL Server Data Tools 15.1.61901.24070
3. SQL Server Management Studio 17.9.1
4. Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4293803) - 14.0.2002.14 (X64) Enterprise Evaluation Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763:)

Accordint to [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/attunity-connectors?view=sql-server-2017) I need [Version 5.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55179) of said Attunity Oracle Drivers. Problem is, if I install these nothing in Visual Studio changes.

There are already some oracle source/destinations (maybe they come trough the oracle software I needed to install on the machine to enable data connections) but I am pretty sure that they are installed with visual studio, hence they are not Attunity "special" Drivers.

Screenshot Oracle SourceDestination

[image]

This leads to the following Questions:

1. Are those the proper Attunity Drivers?
2. Ho do I check this?
3. If not, how do I install the proper drivers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solution**

I finally figured it out: Attunity Drivers only Work on SSDT for VS2017 15.8.0 **NOT** 15.8.1 and later. Previous versions of SSDT can be loaded [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-2017).

(Be prepared to use a browser with the same language as your installation since you can not change language on the page (way to go microsoft..) and installing German (for example) SSDT on English Visual Studio will be refused.)

**Explanation**

To end my initial confusion: It is only Oracle by Attunity if there is a red O in the top left of the Tool.

[image]

You can double check this by looking at the "add connection manager" dialogue - if this points to your attunity-insallation folder you are correct.

[image]

Funny enough, this drivers seem to overwrite to "normal" Oracle Drivers I have been seeing in the inital post.

Be aware that the Numbers in the "About Section" of Visual Studio do not compare to the Version of the Installation Package. The working Versions of SSDT-Tools (15.8.0) are represented in VS as follows:

[image]

**References**

The Changelog for SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) [15.8.1 & 15.8.2] states:

> SSDT for Visual Studio 2017 (15.8.2) doesn't support designing packages that contain Oracle/Teradata source/destination. Use SSDT for Visual Studio 2017 (15.8).

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/changelog-for-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017

Thanks to [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54683977/attunity-connectors-are-not-showing-in-ssis-for-vs-2017-sql-server-2017) leading to this [discuission](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0d45473-eea6-4d19-a708-25ceb79bf920/ssdt-for-visual-studio-2017-1590-and-oracle-connector-requirements?forum=ssdt) giving it away.

Comment: you have to accept this answer even if it is yours. click on the "accepted" mark on the left top of the answer

Answer (score 2):

**Are those the proper Attunity Drivers?**

What i can tell you is that the those are third party components, they are not installed with Visual Studio or SSDT. Also, on the other hand the Attunity Oracle components name are the same (Oracle Source , and Oracle Destination).

But i think that the Oracle Attunity components have different icons:

[image]

Click on the component and read the description at the bottom of the SSIS toolbox it may helps.

*References:*

- [Setup Of Oracle Attunity Connectors](http://blogs.adatis.co.uk/jonathoneveoconnor/post/Setup-Of-Oracle-Attunity-Connectors)
- [MICROSOFT CONNECTORS BY ATTUNITY](https://www.attunity.com/content/microsoft-connectors-attunity/)

**Ho do I check this?**

Check that the components dll are found inside the following directories:

*32-bit*

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\<sql version>\DTS\PipelineComponents\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\<sql version>\DTS\Connections\
```

*64-bit*

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<sql version>\DTS\PipelineComponents\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<sql version>\DTS\Connections\
```

I think that reading the following article should help: *(it is for another third party components but it will give you some insights)*

- [No components in SSIS toolbox](https://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=35839)

**If not, how do I install the proper drivers?**

You can download Attunity drivers from the link below:

- [Microsoft Connectors v5.0 for Oracle and Teradata](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55179)

To choose the appropriate Attunity drivers, you can refer tho the following link:

- [Microsoft Connectors for Oracle and Teradata by Attunity for Integration Services (SSIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/attunity-connectors?view=sql-server-2017#issue---the-attunity-connectors-arent-visible-in-the-ssis-toolbox)