# SSIS Oracle connection manager type not found in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: oracle, ssis, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to create a new SSIS project in visual studio 2017. I installed all the required components,
AttUnity ORA connectors.

When I am trying to create a new connection, I can't see MSORA connection type in visual studio.
[image]

Can someone please help?
SSDT version is 15.9.7.

Comment: Quick guess: You installed  only the x64 Oracle drivers and the SSIS Connection Manager is only able to "see" 32-Bit drivers (at least this was the common issue whenever I had to deal with Oracle and SSIS).

Comment: @Filburt I have installed both versions. The oracle connection type is available in VS 2015. The problem is with VS 2017.

Comment: Does your project run in 32-bit or 64-bit mode? `MSDAORA` exist only in 32-bit.

Comment: The project runs under 64-bit mode

Comment: I got the solution from this post.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54885255/install-oracle-attunity-drivers-in-visual-studio-2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54885255/install-oracle-attunity-drivers-in-visual-studio-2017)